# Register context listener for jersey

Tags: java, servlets, jersey

I need to perform some clean up steps after shutting down a jersey server. To my mind this could be easily accomplished by implementing a [ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). The question of course is how to add this listener to the application. I have seen examples where this is done in the file `web.xml` like this:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.SomeCompany.SomePackage.server.MyListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

where the `MyListener` class looks as follows:

```
@WebListener
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {
```

The problem is that this approach only works for deployment as a war file. However, I do also ship my software as a standalone jar file which creates a Grizzly web server to deploy the servlet:

```
HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI,
                new MyServerConfig());
```

The class `MyServerConfig` subclasses from [ResourceConfig](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.0/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) and uses the various `register` methods. I would like to add the listener programmatically as well, but calling `register` doesn't seem to do the job. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you are going to need to configure Grizzly as a servlet container. This is not the default behavior. You are only creating an HTTP Server. So the first thing you will need to is Grizzly servlet dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

So here's the deal with this. With this artifact, instead of the Grizzly `HttpServer` with `GrizzlyHttpServerFactory`, you would instead use the [`GrizzlyWebContainerFactory`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22.1/jersey/index.html?org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/servlet/GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.html). The only thing is, if you look though the factory API methods, there really isn't a place to register any listeners, and from what I tested, the `@WebListener` annotation will not automatically get picked up. What we need access to is the Grizzly `WebAppContext` that Jersey uses to create the Grizzly servlet container.

The way I was able to get it to work, was just to grab some code from the [`GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create` source code](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.22.1/containers/grizzly2-servlet/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/servlet/GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.java#L244), and just create the container myself. It's really not much code. Most of the source code does checks as it needs to be universal. But in a single use case (with no init-params), you can pretty much cut the code down to this

```
private static HttpServer create(URI u, Servlet servlet) throws IOException {

    String path = u.getPath();
    path = String.format("/%s", UriComponent.decodePath(u.getPath(), true)
                 .get(1).toString());

    WebappContext context = new WebappContext("GrizzlyContext", path);
    context.addListener(MyListener.class);
    ServletRegistration registration;
    registration = context.addServlet(servlet.getClass().getName(), servlet);
    registration.addMapping("/*");

    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(u);
    context.deploy(server);
    return server;
}
```

Then just call `HttpServer server = create(BASE_URI, new ServletContainer(resourceConfig));`

---

As an aside, for your use case (I just re-read the question :-), Jersey also has [Event Listeners](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#d0e15631). You can write an `ApplicationEventListener` and listen for the destroy event, and do all your processing there.

Comment: I did go for an event listener which solved the problem I was having. But using grizzly as a ServletContainer might work as well...